# C# - Send input to child process - console app

Tags: c#, .net, process

#### Background info

I am writing an integration test that spawns a child process (c# console app).  The test is counting some rows in the database after the process is spun up and after the process is closed.  The process is closed via process.Kill()

When the process is killed in this manner, it doesn't hit the Stop method within the process. I need to call this stop method to stop threads and remove entries from the database in order for the test to pass.

#### Original Code

The console app process that I am spawning in my test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TaskManager tm = new TaskManagerProcess();

        if (Environment.UserInteractive ||
            (args.EmptyForNull().Any(a => a.Equals("-RunInteractive", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || a.Equals("/RunInteractive"))))
        {
            tm.ConsoleStart(args);
            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to shut down, any other key to mark");
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    break;
                Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                Console.Out.Flush();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Shutting down...");
            tm.ConsoleStop();
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(tm);
        }
    }
}
```

The test code:

```
        //count before starting child proc
        int preCount;
        //count after process is spun up
        int runningsCount;
        //count after stopped
        int postCount;

        //Get an initial count of the logged in modules before svc host is started
        user = ApiMethod.GetLoggedInUsers().Where(x => x.RecId == userRecID).FirstOrDefault();
        preCount = user.LoggedInModules.Count;

        Process proc = Helper.StartProcess(ConnectionBundle);

        //Give process time to spin up leaders and workers
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        //Get a count of modules after process is spun up
        user = ApiMethod.GetLoggedInUsers().Where(x => x.RecId == userRecID).FirstOrDefault();
        runningCount = user.LoggedInModules.Count;

        //Write a line terminator to the child svc host process -
        //this allows it to shutdown normally
        Helper.ProcessInput.WriteLine();
        Helper.ProcessInput.Close();

        Helper.KillProcess(proc);

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        //Get count of logged in modules after process is closed
        user = ApiMethod.GetLoggedInUsers().Where(x => x.RecId == userRecID).FirstOrDefault();
        postCount = user.LoggedInModules.Count;
```

Helper is a static class that sets up the process start info(including args) and starts the process.  In helper I've redirected the StandardInput and added a property ProcessInput which is set to the StandardInput of the created process.

My goal is to send input of "Enter" from the test to the spawned process so that it will break from the loop and call tm.ConsoleStop()

TaskManagerProcess is a private custom class that controls the process.  It does not inherit from System.Diagnostics.Process. As an alternate approach,  my test could interact with TaskManagerProcess directly. However, I can't make TaskManagerProcess public and I need to run TaskManagerProcess in its own AppDomain because calling ConsoleStop is disposing objects in the API that I need to finish the test.

#### Things I've Tried

```
    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CloseProcDelgate handler, bool add);
```

I tried adding a call to Kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler (and the necessary delegate) to call ConsoleStop when the process is exited.  This doesn't seem to work when the process is killed via process.Kill()

With the original process code, I noticed an exception when I wrote to the StandardInput. The exception message told me to use Console.Read instead of Console.ReadKey(). This actually works intermittently!  I can sometimes get a breakpoint on int cKey = Console.Read()  (with debugger attached to child process) but other times it doesn't hit the breakpoint.

```
while (true)
            {
                //Changing this to Console.Read instead of Console.ReadKey
                //Allows us to send redirected input to process?
                int cKey = Console.Read();
                if ((ConsoleKey)cKey == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    break;

                Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                Console.Out.Flush();
            }
```

Finally, I tried interacting with TaskManagerProcess directly. I made the private class internal, and marked the internals visible to my test assembly.  I cannot make the class public.

When I go this route,  calling tm.ConsoleStop() blows away some objects in my API so I can't check the count after this method is called. For this reason, I thought I would create a new AppDomain and call AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap() on the TaskManagerProcess class.  However, I get an exception here, I believe its due to the the fact that the class is internal.

I am really stuck at this point! Any help is appreciated and thanks for taking the time to read this!

#### Edit

I created a demo project [here](https://github.com/jmaness52/Process_Communication)
that shows what I am trying to do and has both approaches in the Test method.

Initially I thought I couldn't call AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap() because the TaskManagerProcess class was internal.  However, after playing with my demo project, I think I just can't load the assembly.

Comment: Did you write this other application ? if yes, just setup IPC... Anyway my feeling is you should not be writing tests for another application, you should be testing the methods in it

Comment: Hi Michael,

My company wrote the other application.  I'm writing a test for the app after fixing a bug.  I will look into IPC, thank you

Comment: You should be writing the tests for the methods in the application, not for the console app

Comment: [Some example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541090/12888024)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but I believe your TaskManagerProcess is a service application. If it is not, please ignore this. If it is, be advised of including details like this in your question. Debugging service applications can be complicated, believe me, I've been there. But before proceed, more advise.

Test the methods in your modules, no whole running programs, as Michael Randall just said.
Unless absolutely necessary, don't do tests against a database. Mock whatever you need to test your code.

You should go back to your alternate approach of interact with TaskManagerProcess directly. From the code of your console app, the only working method I see called is tm.ConsoleStart(args), the rest inside the loop is console writing and reading. So you can't change the acces level of that class, again, I've been there. What I have done in the past to overcome this is to use conditional compilation to create a kind of public facade in my private or internal modules.

Suppose you have:

```
internal class TaskManagerContainer
{

    private class TaskManagerProcess
    {
        internal void Start()
        {
            // stuff
        }

        private void DoSomething(int arg)
        {
            // more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Change it like this:

```
#define TEST

// Symbol TEST can also be defined using the GUI of your IDE or compiler /define option

internal class TaskManagerContainer
{

//
#if TEST
    public class TaskManagerProcess
#else
    private class TaskManagerProcess
#endif
    {
        internal void Start()
        {
            // stuff
        }

        private void DoSomething(int arg)
        {
            // more stuff
        }

        #region Methods Facade for Testing

#if TEST
        public void Start_Test()
        {
            Start();
        }

        private void DoSomething_Test(int arg)
        {
            DoSomething(arg);
        }
#endif
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I really hope it will help you making the methods visible to the test assembly and it won't blow objects in you API.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I am able to get around making the class visible by marking it as internal and setting the internals visible to my test project in assemblyInfo.cs.  

However, I believe I need to run TaskManagerProcess in its own AppDomain.  If I just just create a new instance in my test class and call ConsoleStop,  it disposes of some things in the static API. Please forgive my ignorance, but I'm not sure how the above example would prevent my API objects from being disposed?

Comment: As for the database, we have a setup to spawn a test database when the test starts. When the test completes, the test database gets deleted.  Almost all of our integration tests spawn this test database.  We even have some existing tests that create the console app in a child process, however the tests don't care if the app gets shut down properly (tm.ConsoleStop()).

If you are feeling bored, I created a demo solution with both approaches that shows what I'm trying to do here: https://github.com/jmaness52/Process_Communication

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I miss the point. Te code is for changing the acces level of the class. A hail mary:  have you tried to put a delay in console app, so it get out of the loop by itself, and avoid the need of sending a keystroke?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it with a brute force approach.

```
 while (!testProcess.HasExited)
 {
     testProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine();
 }
```

Thanks everyone for the input!